# Downloaded page posts from facebook. How do I handle the JSON data?

Tags: python, json, facebook, python-3.x, urllib

I have been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/minimaxir/facebook-page-post-scraper/blob/master/how_to_build_facebook_scraper.ipynb) to download some page info from fb.

I am using Python 3.5 and the tutorial is using python2.

I was having some issues at first with a HTTP error code 400, basically saying I had to use the https protocol instead of http. So I have test in idle now that the data in coming and it looks to a novice like me as JSON. But when I try passing it to the json.loads it is giving this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Levo\Desktop\facebookscrape.py", line 38, in <module>
    testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token)
  File "C:\Users\Levo\Desktop\facebookscrape.py", line 34, in testFacebookPageData
    data = json.loads(requests_until_succeed(url))
  File "C:\Users\Levo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Apart from using the urllib library instead of the urllib2 library and https instead of http I don't what I am doing wrong? is the encryption of https the problem??

```
def requests_until_succeed(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    success = False
    while success is False:
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(5)

            print ("Error for URL %s: %s" % (url, datetime.datetime.now()))

        return response.read()


def testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token):
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6"
    node = "/" + page_id + "/feed"
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters

    data = json.loads(requests_until_succeed(url))

    print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4, sort_keys=True))

testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> json.loads accepts python3 string, which is unicode, and responce.read() returns binary string.

Use `data = json.loads(requests_until_succeed(url).decode('utf-8'))` because responce is most likely utf-8.